# Is it acceptable under kashrut to eat tyrannosauridae meat?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals

Theoretically speaking, if tyrannosaurs were still present these days, or in some way or another brought back, would they be kosher?
Let's assume that they are properly slaughtered and prepared.

Comment: off the cuff, no, as it lacks the signs of a land animal and is not on the given list of birds. http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/wizard_cdo/aid/133726/jewish/Which-Animals-Are-Kosher.htm

Comment: Assuming they are reptiles, probably not.  Do they have split hooves and chew their cud?

Comment: Are they birds or not?

Comment: They are _not_ reptiles, and birds apparently descended from them.

Comment: Earwin, welcome to Jewrassic Park(1), and thanks very much for bringing your interesting question here! I hope you'll look around the site and find other information that's to your taste. [Here](/q/31445/) is a slightly more practical question about dinosaurs, and [here](/q/2668/) is a parallel speculative question about hypothetical kosher pigs. (1) I mean, Mi Yodeya. Sorry to get your hopes up.

Comment: @Scimonster, regardless of heritage, I'm pretty sure that "bird," as far a Jewish Law is concerned, means something like "a thing with wings that's not a little bug." The definition is based on certain aspects of the phenotype, not on the genotype.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @IsaacMoses about the phenotype of birds. Also, as a general rule, birds of prey are on the bad list.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it would be kosher?

Comment: @Scimonster IINM, [halacha-theory] isn't for theoretical halacha -- *all* [halacha] questions should then be so tagged. I think that tag is for questions about *how* halacha works.

Comment: @IsaacMoses About the definition of birds: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50310/5323

Comment: https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya/status/543114121798230016  ;-)

Comment: Two more questions inspired by this one: [fish](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50304/dag-%D7%93%D6%B8%D7%92-in-kashrus-halacha), [land animals](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/what-defines-a-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%94-also-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%94)

Comment: You'd probably be interested in [this similar question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53216/5323), I think.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56208

Comment: I noticed no one mentions the fact that it was an animal of prey, most of such animals aren't considered kosher in most descriptions and commentaries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. No matter how they would be classified:

- Fish: Scales could not be removed without ripping skin.
- Reptile, insect, animal (*Behema*/*Chaya*): Neither a grasshopper, nor split hooves. See picture below.
- Bird:* No mesora for Ashkenazim. For Sefardim, it would need characteristics (*simanim*):

  1. Extant crop: Subject to observation of specimen.
  2. Peelable inner lining of gizzard: Subject to observation of specimen.
  3. Extra claw. Depends on rabbinic opinion. See picture below.
  4. Not a bird of prey. Well, yes. Very much so.

So if not for anything else, it is certainly a bird of prey (*doreis*), which is only kosher with a tradition (*mesora*), which tyrannosauridae of course do not have.

[image: T. Rex foot]

---

<sup>* If it would look like this, it may actually be considered a bird:</sup>
[image: Feathered T. Rex]

Comment: There really isn't any reason to think that Chazal, when formulating the bird-rules, would have accounted for extinct species. Their application here is highly questionable.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am applying the rules to an extant animal, as per OP: *were still present these days, or in some way or another brought back*.

Comment: I know what you're doing. I'm saying applying those rules to species Chazal thought were extinct is questionable.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please source that Chazal thought T. Rex was extinct. :-) Why wouldn't the rules be universal in time?

Comment: They might be, I just see no reason to claim they are.

Comment: Torah classification of wildlife is never related to genotyping, evolutionary background, etc. but rather straightforward physical similarities (e.g. what would a guy on the street consider it). The famous example is that bats are classified as birds even though they're zoologically classified with mammals. Vayikra 11:19. I recommend Prof Yehuda Felix regarding topics of Torah + wildlife. Also Slifkin discusses classification in his `The Camel, The Hare, And The Hyrax`. I think then it's likely that dinosaurs would have been classified as a `chayah`.

Comment: @ChaimKut If that average gay on the street would see the footnote's picture, do you think he would call it a *chaya* or bird?

Comment: Love the pictures, well-done! .....I can corroborate a lot of the information here, just from past experience of talking to *shochtim* ....but some written sources for these claims would greatly improve this (already awesome) answer.

Answer (score 12):

I would think not, because they *probably* wouldn't be kosher animals.

The basic requirements for being a kosher animal are laid out in [Deuteronomy 14:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9978#v=6):

> וְכָל בְּהֵמָה מַפְרֶסֶת פַּרְסָה וְשֹׁסַעַת שֶׁסַע שְׁתֵּי פְרָסוֹת
>   מַעֲלַת גֵּרָה בַּבְּהֵמָה אֹתָהּ תֹּאכֵלוּ
>
> And every animal that has a split hoof and has a hoof cloven into two
>   hoof sections, [and] chews the cud among the animals that you may eat.

( *Chabad text and translation* )

I don't think that tyrannosaurs had split hooves; I'm pretty sure that they didn't chew their cud, either.

If you'd rather consider them birds, they would be forbidden anyway.

Mishna, [Chullin 3:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chullin.3.6)

> סִימָנֵי בְהֵמָה וְחַיָּה {ל} נֶאֶמְרוּ מִן הַתּוֹרָה, וְסִימָנֵי
>   הָעוֹף לֹא נֶאֱמָרוּ. אֲבָל אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים, **כָּל עוֹף הַדּוֹרֵס,
>   טָמֵא.** כֹּל שֶׁיֶּשׁ לוֹ אֶצְבַּע יְתֵרָה, וְזֶפֶק, וְקֻרְקְבָנוֹ
>   נִקְלָף, טָהוֹר. רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בַּר צָדוֹק אוֹמֵר, כָּל עוֹף
>   הַחוֹלֵק אֶת רַגְלָיו, טָמֵא
>
> The signs by which the clean animals, domestic and wild, may be
>   distinguished [from the unclean and prohibited ones] are mentioned in
>   the Holy Law, but not those of fowl. The sages have, however,
>   established, "**That every [predaceous] bird**, which strikes its
>   talons into its prey, **is of the unclean**: every bird which has an
>   additional claw, a crop, and of which the internal coat of the stomach
>   may be readily peeled off, is of the clean species." R. Eleazar ben
>   Zadok saith, "Every bird which [when placed on a perch] divides its
>   toes equally, is an unclean one."

( *Sefaria translation* )

I think we all agree that the T-rex was predatory :)

Also, if it would be classified as a bird, it would be missing the critical aspect of "מסורה," a "tradition" that was passed down that this "bird" is kosher.
See [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 82:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4192):

> וְעוֹף טָהוֹר נֶאֱכָל בְּמָסֹרֶת, וְהוּא שֶׁיִּהְיֶה דָּבָר פָּשׁוּט
>   בְּאוֹתוֹ מָקוֹם שֶׁזֶּה עוֹף טָהוֹר
>
> Kosher birds are eaten by "tradition," which means that it's known by
>   the people of that place that this is a kosher bird.

See also Rema to [Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 82:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4192):

> וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁאֵין לִסְמֹךְ אֲפִלּוּ עַל זֶה, וְאֵין לֶאֱכֹל שׁוּם עוֹף אֶלָּא (ח) בַּמָּסֹרֶת שֶׁקִּבְּלוּ בּוֹ שֶׁהוּא טָהוֹר (בְּאָרֹךְ כְּלָל נ''ו ובתא''ו נט''ו), וְכֵן 
>   נוֹהֲגִין, וְאֵין לְשַׁנּוֹת
>
> Some say that you cannot rely even on this (to check the size and shape of the beak), and one cannot eat any bird unless there is an accepted "tradition" that this is a kosher bird. This is how we've decided to act, and one cannot change from this.

( *above translations are my own* )

Comment: It may be worthwhile to tighten this to indicate that it refers specifically to something like "non-bug land animals."

Comment: But, they are more likely to be considered birds, are they not? They have feathers, they lay eggs. And I fail to find a definite list of requirements for a bird to be kosher. i.e. is being a non-predator a requirement?

Comment: @Earwin, given that they didn't have wings, I think it's be unlikely that they'd be governed by the rules concerning "birds." FYI, the Torah presents a list of kosher birds that is considered to be exhaustive. Any bird that isn't identified by tradition as one of those on the list is out.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I thought the list is of unkosher birds.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Please source T. Rex not having wings.

Comment: @NBZ המוציא מחברו... Can you prove that they did?

Comment: @Scimonster Even if such a creature ever lived, it would be irrelevant. The question is if such a thing was alive today, in which case we would have to take a look to determine if it has wings. However, Issac Moses said "given", without a source, and *haomer davar beshem omro*...

Comment: @NBZ If its existence historically is irrelevant, why'd you ask Isaac for proof?

Comment: @Scimonster No, you are the Motzi Mechaveiro as you (are defending Shokhet who) is trying to answer the question. The onus is on the one trying to answer to show that they did not have wings.

Comment: @Earwin Yeah, it would appear that even if it would be classified as a bird, it would still not be kosher, as per the information I added to my answer. ( *I wrote that up during a period of time that I didn't have access to MY, hence my jumping in later and missing all the comments on my answer* )

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks for the expanded answer. The "tradition" piece is quite interesting, as it looks self-sustaining to me. What I mean is, the ground cause for the "tradition" should not necessarily be known, the fact that "it always was so" is enough. Am I right? Then it begets the question of how the tradition may be established, i.e. with the settlers arriving into a completely new environment. But that probably should be split off into a question of its own.

Comment: @Earwin Yes, that's a very good question. One specific bird that has been under discussion for this reason for some while is the American turkey. See the discussion [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22315/5323) for more about the tradition of turkeys. Rabbi Ari Zivotofsky also published an article on turkeys a while back....if I can find it again I might post another answer to that question ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let's see. What exactly are dinosaurs?

For a long time, they have been considered lizards. Lizards are not kosher, due to lack of kosher signs.

For the sake of argument, they might be mammals. In that case, they're still not kosher, as they don't have split hooves and chew their cud. (Also brought by [Shokhet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50295/5151))

What if they're birds? The Torah (Devarim 14:11-20) gives a list of non-kosher birds, so it seems that everything else is kosher. Now, it might just be me, but דינוזרים (dinosaurs) aren't on that list. But wait! Maybe they are - the word "dinosaur" is relatively modern.
The truth is that we've lost the mesorah for what most of them are, so we only allow birds known to be kosher.
One thing all of the no-noes have in common is that they are birds of prey, or at the very least, scavengers. T. Rex was either a hunter or a scavenger.

A more interesting question would be about herbivorous dinosaurs - could those possibly be kosher??

Comment: "Lizards are not kosher." Why not? What if the requisite foot-structure and chewed its cud?

Comment: Yeah, but lizards *don't* have the "requisite foot structure" or chew their cud.

Comment: All extant lizards TTBOMK do not have those properties. So what? Is there a reason there couldn't be a lizard that had them?

Comment: So then we look - do they fulfill those qualities? And the answer is no, neither lizards nor dinosaurs have split hooves, nor chew their cud. (TTBOMK)

Comment: Very likely dinosaurs did not have those qualities and would not have been kosher. But you cannot prove that from the made-up law "lizards are not kosher" because it is not a law.

Comment: I implicitly reject the opinion of dinosaurs being lizards later anyways.

Comment: @DoubleAA, then it wouldn't be a lizard. How's that for an answer? If you discovered a scaly, cold-blooded creature that chewed its cud and had split hooves, you'd have discovered a new Class of animal.

Comment: @SethJ Sounds like you're defining yourself into a logical circle: Dinosaur isn't kosher because it's a lizard. Lizard is something which isn't kosher.

Comment: How's that a circle? It's a straight line (albeit in reverse, the way you've stated it).

Comment: It is quite established that dinosaurs were not lizards although they resemble them