# Would the Dinosaurs Be Clean or Unclean by Torah Standards

Tags: food

Based on what we know of Dinosaur anatomy, would **Dinosaurs** have been **clean or unclean** by the standards Moses gave? I am referring to the Cretaceous, or the periods typically defined by the "Terrible Lizard" species.

I am not a Jew (rather Christian), so forgive the possible foolishness of the question. As somewhat of a bible scholar I find some interest in where the Dinos fit in during the creation process. God had told the Jews what was clean / unclean for eating, and suddenly I realize there are entire periods possibly dominated by "unclean" animals! Very interesting.

**UPDATE** This questions includes sea bound (like "fish") and flying (like "birds") as well as land bound herbivores. How would they be classified?

Comment: Please note this is a hypothetical question - I'm aware the Jews didn't know of such animals - but I'm asking from a standards perspective, based on their law and what is known of the anatomy of the Dinos.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Betcha didn't expect this one to have been addressed already. :) [Is it acceptable under kashrut to eat tyrannosauridae meat?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50293/is-it-acceptable-under-kashrut-to-eat-tyrannosauridae-meat)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because that question asks about a species of dinosaur.

Comment: @IsaacMoses ^^^^

Comment: There are some (modern) commentaries that say that the ratio changed because of the flood.

Comment: The other question deals only with tyranasaurus which is meat eationg. Need to also deal with hebivores and flying species.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would not be kosher for consumption. Dinosaurs are either a) reptiles, or b) birds of prey, both of which are forbidden by the book of Leviticus in Chapter 11

Comment: That's a stretch. Modern birds might indeed be related to dinosaurs, but to say that dinosaurs _are_ birds definitely stretches the reality.

Comment: ... Moreover, many dinosaurs were vegetarians.

Comment: @Daniel i said they were one or the other, not making anything definitive. Even if they are somewhere in between, or neither, still forbidden by Lev 11

Comment: are you completely sure that there wasn't a single dinosaur with split hooves that chewed its cud?

Comment: @Daniel ive never heard of such a thing. If you can find one I would change my statement

Comment: you're writing the answer here. You have the burden of proof. If you can show that there is no such thing, I will retract my downvote.

Comment: @Daniel the question is already closed.