# Corn as kitniot

Tags: minhag, food, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Traditionally, most if not all observant *Ashkenazim* refrain from eating corn and corn-products on Passover because of their traditional prohibition on eating *kitniyot* (legumes) for fear of eating Biblically-prohibited *chametz* (leavened products). Corn, or  maize, is a New World crop that could only have been imported to Europe once this was feasible. What is the earliest source in the rabbinic literature to classify corn as *kitniyot* and is it universally accepted as such? (I believe I have noticed in recent years a package of "kosher for passover" sweets that suggests Rav Isaac Elhanan Specter, z"l, was lenient, but I am looking for more specific sources.)

Comment: [This answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12865/3483) attributes it to linguistic confusion over "corn" often meaning "grain" but does not source that assertion.

Comment: @Mike not saying that's *THE* reason, just that it further hurt it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I'd seen it printed *somewhere* on the daf in Shulchan Aruch, but would have to dig some more. (The other problem is that everyone is giving the local Yiddish-ish word for these plants, which can be tricky to translate.)

Don't be fooled by the sweets package! It contains corn syrup; the argument is "Rabbi Yitzchak Elchanan Specter allowed all liquid kitniyot." No, he allowed *oil* extracted from kitniyot, as there's little concern of confusion or contamination with regards to the oil. Corn *syrup* is converted from the grain itself. (Regardless, the argument isn't "corn isn't kitniyot"; it's that corn syrup isn't the same as corn.)

Comment: And i think it's only oil or syrup from kitnios that was cooked before Pesach, to facilitate bittul.

Comment: Oil is also converted from the grain itself.