# Were flour tortillas invented by the Jews of New Spain?

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, food, marranos-conversos

I was reading the **[Wikipedia entry for tortilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortilla)**. It says,

> The wheat flour tortilla was an innovation by exiled Spanish Jews who
>   did not consider corn meal to be kosher, using wheat brought from
>   Europe, while this region was the colony of New Spain. It is made with
>   an unleavened, water based dough, pressed and cooked like corn
>   tortillas.

I checked the sources, but only found one, a brief article in Tex-Arcana (a Houston Chronicle publication), **["What's the history of tortillas? Tradition traced to ancient culture"](http://www.chron.com/news/houston-texas/article/Tex-Arcana-What-s-the-history-of-tortillas-1752733.php)**. The ancient culture is Judaism:

> Jewish families — covertly practicing their faith or simply
>   maintaining their traditions as Catholic conversos — settled in
>   northern Mexico to get as far from the Spanish Inquisition as
>   possible. Since corn was not kosher and they were accustomed to eating
>   flat pita bread, they began to make tortillas out of wheat...

Is this factually accurate?

Comment: Why would corn not be considered kosher?

Comment: *Matzoth* are a lot older than that.

Comment: Maybe it was a covert way of makin matzos?

Comment: Could the reference to corn mean kitniyos on pesach?

Comment: @Maimonist I'm just guessing, but maybe it is due to this, [Corn as Kitniot?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56551/corn-as-kitniot) I am OP, so I looked at that and similar questions before asking this one.

Comment: Maybe they avoided corn as suspect, since it was unknown in the old country. In other words, that they feared it wasn't kosher, not that it wasn't in fact kosher.

Comment: I might suggest that this was a bishul akum issue, and while chazzal only disallowed bread of the five grains when baked by a private baker, the item cooked would still be disallowed if it is 'served on a king's table', which we can assume this staple was. Being cooked by a professional baker would not come into play. This is all assuming they had it baked by non-jews, of course, which is a big old who says so.

Comment: I know this to be absolutely true, since I am married to one of these descendants and I heard from them that this is the case.

Comment: This might get better answers if we migrate it to Skeptics.SE

Comment: @DoubleAA Evidence given lack of response to the question indicates that you are likely to be correct! Can you facilitate migration of the question to Skeptics.SE for me?

Comment: @EllieKesselman Sorry, I see now it's too old to migrate (we can only migrate questions within the first 6 (?) months or so) You can just ask again there as a new post.

Comment: @msh210, it could be a question of mezonot vs. sheakol

Answer (score 4):

Corn is kosher. It is ignorant to state corn is not kosher. All vegetables free from bugs are kosher to eat. There is a 17th Mexican Inquisition trial where a Converso (i.e. descendant of Sephardic Jews converted to Christianity) only ate corn tortillas during Passover, instead of leavened bread. Any leavened wheat flour product is forbidden to eat during Passover. Check Gitlitz' Secrecy and Deceit for the Inquisition trial source.
Although the idea that Conversos may have brought the innovation, to my understanding flat bread was not a feature of the Iberian Jewish diet. In all probability, the adaptation from corn to flour was brought about because in the north of Mexico corn is not a staple that grows abundantly.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya David!

Comment: Corn is kosher: that's correct, but may not have been obvious at the time (though I have no idea what their rationale would have been to forbid it)