# Why is corn a forbidden kitniyot?

Tags: halacha, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Was reading halakhic discourse given [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=&ClipID=3074) that said the following:

> In later generations, the Ashkenazi Poskim discuss whether other foods, such as coffee beans, peanuts and quinoa, would also be considered “Kitniyot.” Rav Shlomo Amar and Rav Moshe Feinstein rule that any food that wasn’t known in the Western world at the time of the original institution of the Gezera was not included in the custom.

However, corn is a new world crop, and when the Gezera was instituted no one would have even known corn existed. So if the halakhic justification that allows Ashkenazim to use coffee beans and cocoa beans (chocolate) during Pesach is that new world foods don't count as "kitniyot", then why is corn forbidden?

Comment: It's usually not worth reading what Sefardim have to say about how Ashkenazim should keep their tradition of Kitniyot, and this is no exception.

Comment: My response to your source: potatoes were completely unknown at the time of the gezeira. Furthrermore, I have never met someone who doesn't eat kitnyiot but eats peanuts. In addition, R' Shlomo 'Amar is Maghribi, which is to say, I would not even look at his writing on Ashkenazi practice as it has no validity for Ashkenazim.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt And Rav Feinstein?

Comment: @Aaron He doesn't just say what they quote him as saying. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=366

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt My family is eating peanuts this year. Apparently the OU only banned them because of one very vocal community back in the '70s. But i didn't really follow the discussion that much because i can't stand the taste of peanuts ever.

Comment: Didnt the chayai odom asser potatoes.  One should remember the Yaavets who says rather eat kitniyot than "todays" matzot.

Comment: עוד ראיתי שכתב בעל חיי אדם שרצה לאסור בפסח אף תפוחי אדמה, מפני שמחמיצין, ואך מפני שפרנסת עניי רוסיא ופולין היא מתפוחי אדמה, לכן שלחו לו בזו הלשון: "הגאון בעל חיי אדם, דע כי חיי האדם, הם תפוחי האדמה   http://www.haokets.org/2016/04/19/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%97-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95/

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56551/759

Comment: @DoubleAA It is close. But in the end the OP is asking for a source that forbids corn, i'm asking why is it forbidden when other similar kitniyot that are not.

Comment: @Aaron what's the difference?

Comment: @newcomer where did the yaavetz say that?

Comment: in mor ukzioh on the shulchan aruch about kitniyot. @ShmuelBrin I would have thought the chayai odom would be considered a good source.

Comment: @newcomer though his Chashash of kneeding the Matza for too long was nisbatel not long after his passing.

Comment: @Aaron, the website is Syrian, which means that it is mizraḥi, which is in common parlance Sephardi.

Comment: @Scimonster, your family in Israel, or bchu"l?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt So he's not saying anything valid? (not trying to be argumentative, just wondering if he has his facts straight or not)

Comment: He just does not seem to understand kitniyot well.

Comment: The fact that it was discovered in American Continent introduces a new doubt: may be that Corn is a 5 minim derivate, not Kitniot but  Dagan Gamur!

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt We're in Israel; i'm not sure what the American side of the family is doing. But we're basing it on the fact that family mesora (from chu"l), as testified by my grandparents, is to eat peanuts.

Answer (score 3):

According to Rabbi Yehuda Shurpin ([chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/2898614)): The Shulchan Aruch HaRav (Orech Chaim 453:3-4) applies the prohibition of kitniyot to any legume-like foods which look similar to dishes made from grain when cooked. Also, certain foods, such as mustard seeds, are prohibited because they grow in pods similar to legumes; and cumin is prohibited because its seeds are similar to grain. So corn would be considered kitniyot because it grows in a similar fashion to the traditional grains and legumes and can be made into flour and bread.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein wrote (Iggrot Moshe, Orech Chaim 3:63) that the custom not to eat kitniyot on Passover was not created by a group of rabbis issuing a formal ban; rather different communities developed the custom of refraining from  certain foods on Passover because they could be mistaken for chametz or they were grown or processed in proximity to flour. These customs eventually became accepted among Ashkenazic Jews, and once a custom has become widely accepted, it has the force of Jewish law.

[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corn) has this to say about the word corn:

> Originally, the English word corn meant any rounded grain or seed
>   whatsoever. In particular, it was used to refer to the kind of grain
>   most often grown in a certain region. Thus in England, a cornfield is
>   usually a field of wheat. The pretty blue cornflower is a Eurasian
>   weed that originally plagued fields of wheat, not maize. In Scotland,
>   on the other hand, corn can mean "oats," the grain that thrives best
>   in Scotland's cool and damp climate. To modern North Americans,
>   however, corn means maize.

According to Yehuda Shurpin ([chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/871998)), it appears that the popularity of corn to the extent that it was named as *the* grain in North America – was sufficient cause for the custom of kitniyot to be extended to this previously unknown "grain". A custom which has now become widely accepted.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Constructive criticism would allow me to correct whatever it is about the answer that is not found pleasing.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter so I can only guess, but perhaps s/he felt that there needs to be a stronger case presented to prove that kitnios were abstained from based on names and word associations.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that in Scotland, "corn" refers to maize too and not oats.  I'm saying that as someone who lives in the North of England.  To the best of my knowledge, the whole of the UK normally refers to maize as "corn".

Comment: @wizzardmr42 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96522/73878

Comment: @Baruch I'm not convinced that answer is up to date.  I have never heard anyone refer to any other grain with the word "corn" in the UK and I have lived here my whole life (33 years).  It may have been true in the 19th century and some dictionaries still seem to reflect that, but in practical terms these days "corn" in the UK means maize.

Comment: @wizzardmr42 The fact that the meaning of "corn" has changed over time from "grain" to "maize" is evidence of a strong association between the two in people's minds. That you have not heard the word used with its old meaning is beside the point.