Choose his posek halacha
Chalom,
Do we choose a posek halacha according to the edah he belongs (should he be from the same edah as the talmid)?

No, a strong posek will know how to rule for the talmid based on the talmid's edah. You see very often in R Ovadia Yosef for instance that he gives the ruling for Sefaradim then for Ashkenazim. My Rav does the same, asking people according to who they go then giving them a ruling

Yes but  can psakim from one edah be adopted by an another one?

Ask your posek :-> But no, Ashkenazim should follow the Rema/Mishna Brura/Aruch Hashulchan and Sefaradim the Shulchan Aruch/R Ovadia Yosef/etc.

@mbloch Overconfident poskim not strong ones. Eg. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70738/why-is-corn-a-forbidden-kitniyot#comment204344_70738

The only rule is to choose a posek you trust. It's up to them to deal with getting you the right answer. That's the whole point of the system.
