# Is triangle k a reliable hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

I heard that they're upping up their level of kashrut recently. I also heard that there are many different types of triangle k signs.

Comment: The reliability of a hechsher is subjective. Please reword this to somehow incorporate an objectively measurable benchmark. E.g. approval by Star-K, or Chuf-K.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11694

Comment: Although @mevaqesh's description of a question would make this an exact duplicate, the current question and this duplicate are not the same. This asks about possible recent changes in the Triangle K's standards as well as a general statement of reliability (which can be given by third party observers, Rabbis, etc., not just other certification organizations).