# Are these cookies kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

These cookies have no certification on the box itself, it is made in a spanish speaking country. yet they have a sticker with a kosher certification put on them.

is this reliable?

[image]

[image]

This is not a practical question.

Comment: You can call the kashrus  organization on the label to verify.

Comment: i tried, i was given the number to rabbi ralbags house and nobody picked up, called many times

Comment: Well I don't know your community affiliations, but most people I know don't like relying on triangle k at all. I'm not trying to sway your opinion in any way, But at least in this case of uncertainty, it may be something to think about.

Comment: I am Religious, i keep kosher to the fullest

Comment: Oh. I meant chassidish yeshivish modern orthodox datei liumi. Stuff like that. Unfortunately kashrus is accepted almost as much by societal possibly imagined politics as it is by halacha so that's why I made that comment.

Comment: @user6591 It also says it's certified by the Rabanut.

Comment: @Scimonster The ishur of the Rabanut doesn't mean that the Rabanut supervises it. It just means that they are confirming that Triangle-K certifies it. In any case, many of the people who don't eat Triangle-K also don't eat Rabanut

Comment: In U.S., I believe that Oreos are certified by OU, which many people rely on. From the Hebrew, I assume you live in Israel. Had I known about this earlier, I could have sent you a bunch with my son ;-) Re Rabbi Ralbag, I heard that he died many years ago, which is one of the reasons why most people distrust the Triangle K hashgacha. Personally, I will use Triangle K only for all natural ingredient products (like frozen pineapple, etc.)

Comment: these are not certified by the OU, i was told by a representative of OU in israel

Comment: Stickets like that are very common when products are being exported to another country that has different food labeling requirements. I see it all the time, especially in places like Israel where a lot of food is imported from non-Hebrew speaking countries.

Answer (score 8):

This label is on many products in Israel. In my experience, most people do trust the sticker labels; however, to be safe, when you see a product with the kosher certification stuck on a sticker to the box, it certainly cannot hurt to call the certifying agency to confirm that they do supervise that particular item.

As a separate issue, many people do not rely on the particular kosher certifying agency shown on this label (Triangle-K). The majority of major kashrus agencies do not recommend consuming food with only the Triangle-K certification.

See [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11694/1713) and its answers.

Comment: It's worth noting that the kashrut of these cookies have been approved by the Israeli rabbinate, as shown inside the marked circle. Even if "many people do not rely" on Triangle-K, the Israeli rabbinate considers them reliable.

Comment: @Aryeh [See this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60558/are-these-cookies-kosher/60560?noredirect=1#comment163480_60558)