# Are Lindeman's fruit lambic beers endorsed as kosher by any other agencies?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, hechsher-certification, liquor-beer

[Lindeman's Beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemans_Brewery) has a hechsher from the Triangle K. This hechsher is recommended (by many kosher agencies) only for certain products. Is there another organization that has also verified the koshrus of this product?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean their fruit or flavored beers? If you're just talking about a plain-old Belgian beer containing nothing other than grain, hops, and yeast, it's basically a non-issue, kashrus-wise.

[cRc's policy](http://www.crcweb.org/LiquorList.pdf):

> All standard unflavored beers with no additives are
>   acceptable, even without Kosher certification. This
>   applies to both American and imported beers, light, dark
>   and non-alcoholic beers. Flavored beer, including those
>   flavored with spices, botanicals, or fruits, require
>   hashgachah.

(Though I believe the Star-K prefers to give a blank check only to domestic unflavored beers, just to play it extra-safe.)

Comment: edited.. concerning lindemans the crc has said... "That hashgacha is only recommended for certain products. We don’t have info on the product you mentioned."

Comment: @Dude a plain-grain beer doesn't need any hashgacha! For something more complicated like a fruit beer ... yeah, I don't think anyone has better information. I would avoid it.