# Triangle-K hechcher for butter

Tags: hechsher-certification

I know there are issues with the Triangle-K hechcher and I know we've talked about it:
[Is there a problem with Triangle K?  If so, what?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/is-there-a-problem-with-triangle-k-if-so-what)

But the only butter that's kosher for Passover that I could find was Triangle-K.  Any reason to suspect **IT** in particular?

(Edit:  My wife reminds me it was dairy, not parve.)

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to deduce from the problems with Triangle-K whether this is permissible or not? (Spoiler alert: it's not.) Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Best thing to do is to contact the Triangle K with your concerns and I am sure they will answer your questions.

Comment: @DonielF -- No.  I am too dumb.

Comment: @sam More likely he should contact, say, OU or Star-K or CRC or whatever kashrus authority he holds by

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea,since there is a bias involved, if you call triangle k and ask them what protocols they follow they will tell you,if your ok with it ,good ,if not, not

Answer (score 1):

There is an argument to be made that pure traditional butter is inherently kosher as milk from non-kosher animals won't congeal properly. Modern butter plants at times utilize whey left over from cheese production as a substitute for costly butterfat when making butter, and Rav Moshe Feinstein went so far as to argue that butter incorporating whey from non-kosher cheese was still kosher. (See OK Kosher's discussion here http://www.ok.org/isitkosher/is-butterkosher)

If you want to hold by the above, any dairy butter will be kosher "year round and for Passover", certainly including butter with any type of kosher supervision whatsoever. If you do not want to hold by the above, you will have to talk to the Triangle-k people and see what their process is and if it satisfies you.

One final note: given that dairy butter has no reason to contain chametz or kitniyot and is not commonly processed in plants where chametz is processed, why not just buy a standard "year round" kosher butter certified by a hechescher of your choosing?