# Reliability of the OKS

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

I dont know if this type of question is allowed but I was [told to ask it here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2764966#2764966)

The symbol [image: OKS] is on some restaurants in the NY tri-state area (like [Crumbs Bake Shop](http://www.crumbs.com/orderinfo/kosher) for example) and I have heard of quite a few people that eat at establishments that are under the OKS.

What are the issues with OKS?

I asked a reliable source who works for a reputable hechsher who said:

> OKS is not considered a reliable hechsher

---

Of interest in responses:

- Official policies of the organization
- Ability of the organization to execute on those policies
- Official policy of other kashrut organizations regarding OKS

Not of interest:

- Stories of what you've heard "through the grapevine"
- Stories about what individuals do or do not hold by this hecksher.
- General pontification on kashrut, the state of kashrut in America, how delicious the cupcakes must be, recipes, culinary wisdom, or the like.

Thanks!

Comment: Copied from http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9728. (Just mentioning to avoid copyright problems: the license under which posts are released requires attribution. (IANAL.))

Comment: I once researched this organization online, and got the general impression that it wasn't the most reliable. But I was unable to find any conclusive evidence.  I recommend that you ask the OU Kashrut division, your local Va'ad, the Kaf-K organization, and\or http://www.kashrut.com/

Comment: I would contact the rav hamachshir, R' Harry Cohen, and ask him what his standards are. In the case of Crumbs, they do the baking and food preparations off the premises, and I would assume that those facilities are under more stringent supervision.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11694/is-there-a-problem-with-triangle-k-if-so-what

Comment: Just found this http://yeahthatskosher.com/2016/03/breaking-news-crumbs-bake-shop-has-lost-its-kosher-certification/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope this goes some way in answering your question:

When I used to live in New York, I had never before seen such a huge proliferation of Kashrut organisations. I asked different Rabbonim, who all "held by" different hashgachot. Ultimately, I decided to personally check out the few places with hechsherim I had not been advised about.

I went into a Crumbs Bake Shop, and I asked about their Kashrut. They had never met anyone from OKS, and claimed to have never been inspected. The woman behind the counter had worked there for over a year. I asked her openly if staff brought in outside food into the store , and she answered "of course" - she in fact told me that she had eaten a Subway sub that lunchtime behind the counter. This is, of course, potentially an isolated example of a store under OKS supervision - however, I did in fact call and leave 3 messages for Rabbi Cohen at OKS to ask about it, and never heard back.

This is my personal experience of OKS. I have asked the OU and London Beth Din for a comment on the OKS hashgacha. I will post it as soon as I hear.

I hope this helps.
Jeremy

Comment: Thanks ^_^ let me know if and when you hear anything ^_^

Comment: Jeremy, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this data point! Please edit [your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1163/user1163) and give yourself a name, unless you happen to like user1163. :) I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: That's not good at all. And in new York, there's definitely no shortage of mashgichim

Comment: Just found this http://yeahthatskosher.com/2016/03/breaking-news-crumbs-bake-shop-has-lost-its-kosher-certification/

Answer (score -3):

Most people who are commenting here do not know anything about the bakery business. Nothing in Crumbs Bake Shop is actually made by them. It's made by a factory called Malita. They are supervised by both OKS and Chof K. 
Rabbi Cohen personally goes there every week and stays there for hours checking everything. The staff told me how he is more stringhnet than all of the other hechshers they have used before.

I had a chance to talk with Rabbi Cohen. He is a mumche in hilchos kashrus. He himself doesn't even eat meat with an OU supervision due to the kulas they follow.

The only reason people don't know about him is because he is not involved with politics and doesn't have a nice website. 
I highly recommend his kashrut.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this answer provides personal testimony that goes to "ability of the organization to execute on those policies." I agree that as it is only personal testimony from a pseudonym on the Internet, it's not very valuable.

Comment: +1 This post is written correctly and provides relevant information. However, personal testimony by an anonymous user has no validity from a Halachik standpoint. Ed Echad is not applicable...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog