# Leniencies for someone keeping Kosher in a non-Kosher home

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, family-members, baal-teshuva, leniencies

My family is not frum, but they do not eat non-kosher meat at home, although they do eat other not-certified-kosher products, including cheese. They don't mix meat and milk, but they do wash meat and milk dishes together. Although I have kept kosher for a while now, this is the first time (since I started keeping kosher) that I will be living at home for a significant period of time. I have my own glass dishes and my own cutlery, but I have been eating food made in my family's pots/pans, etc. Are there ANY leniencies that a person in this situation, can rely on to eat this food or use their dishes?

Comment: Sean, thank you for bringing your very relevant and personal question here. I'd like to remind you that this site does not provide a substitute for qualified rabbinic advice. Anything you read here should be treated as something you heard from a friend and used to help better discuss the issues with your personal rabbi. I wish you the best in finding a way to live comfortably with your family.

Comment: Are you asking for kulot, or f you may rely on such kulot?

Comment: Double AA - I know I need to consult with a Rabbi, I'm just looking for a general idea for now.
I am looking for what kulot exist (for example, I once heard something about using dishes that hadn't been used in a day...I don't know the details, but things along those lines)

Comment: @Sean No need to defend yourself; a reminder is by no means an accusation! :)

Comment: Another thing that came up recently is the cutting board. It is wood and is used for both meat and dairy. Can I cut cold food on that (beside from dvar charif)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be some wiggle room for you regarding [nosein ta'am bar nosein ta'am](http://koltorah.org/ravj/13-13%20Milk%20and%20Meat%20-%20Part%201.htm). Keep in mind that these are intricate and complicated halachos, and subtle differences in the particulars of a case can have a profound impact on the applicable halacha. As can never be reiterated enough with respect to issur v'heter, CYLOR.

Comment: @Fred I was actually gonna add this to my answer. Are you referring to Nat bar bat dehetera or de'isura? I don't think you need "wiggle room" to follow what Maran HaBet Yosef considers halacha. I also think your answer would be much more helpful if you explain the concept, not just name it.

Comment: Coming across this discussion some 7 years after it happened — the comments help me see how this was one of the first answer by someone who would go on to help so many people!

Answer (score 6):

One possibility: see the opinion of R. Raphael Saffra cited in Shoshi's [answer about the Tablet-K hechsher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14991/37), that cheese made without real rennet is permissible. While this opinion isn't generally accepted (and indeed that's why, as mentioned in that answer and several other ones, neither is that hechsher), **perhaps** that might give you halachic wiggle room to at least eat other kinds of food made in your family's pots and pans, even if not the cheese dishes themselves. (As you've already mentioned in a comment on the question, this is of course something about which to consult with your rabbi.)

You mention in that comment also about dishes that haven't been used in 24 hours. Provided that there is no visible food residue left on them, then indeed halachah considers that the taste of the food molecules absorbed into the dish is *pagum* ("impaired") and doesn't have the same capability as before to render food treif. This can get pretty complicated, though, and I don't know whether washing the dishes during this time (in hot water, naturally) resets the 24-hour clock; but again, that's something for a rav to decide.

In any case, I wish you hatzlachah, and an easy time of it, in your Jewish journey!

Answer (score 6):

You mentioned dishes being washed together. Hacham Ovadia Yosef  writes in Yabia Omer (Y"D 10:4) that you may wash meat and milk dishes together in a dishwasher as long as the first rinse contains soap (and not just hot water). Presumably, this would also work for non-kosher dishes because the laws of disqualified food (such as if it's mixed with soap) apply to non-kosher food too, not just milk and meat.

Comment: @ه ه The two cases might be different, because you cannot Mevatel Isur לכתחילה like you can with Heter.

Comment: @SethJ I'm not so sure noten ta'am lifgam is considered mevatel issur. Perhaps it is.

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot That would seem to be a machloket rishonim.

Answer (score 3):

Having been through this before, trying to find leniences to use in my parents' home created a lot of friction that could have been avoided if I had simply stuck to my standards.

Comment: I hear that, but I also feel that I am living in their home and I should try to stick as close as I (halachically) can to doing things their way

Comment: This flies in the face of my Rav's teachings. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Consult the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch and the Ben Ish HAi.  Among Sephardic authorities glass dishes are not porous.  Therefore, they cannot become nonkosher by eating meat or dairy on them.  Though the dishes must be eaten separately.  They must be taken to a Mikvah for purification.  Metal pots and pans have to be made kosher through both a Mikvah and boiling between use.  Better to buy your own pot pan and dishes.  You must also buy your own silverware, however, these can also be boiled.  A person my keep kosher by eating cold foods and being a vegan or vegatarian.  This is not only easier when around non-Jews or Jews that do not keep kosher, but healthier.  Anyother questions, please ask.

Comment: Why do metal pots require re-immersion if they are owned by the same (Jewish) people?